# SSLPeerUnverifiedException in basic twilio-java app

Tags: java, macos, ssl, certificate, twilio

I'm following the [Twilio-java example from the github page.](https://github.com/twilio/twilio-java)

Here's the code snippet I wrote:

```
    private boolean doSms(Notification notification) {
    String message = "test";
    try {
        final MessageFactory messageFactory = mainAccount.getMessageFactory();
        final List<NameValuePair> messageParams = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
        messageParams.add(new BasicNameValuePair("To", notification.getUser().getPhoneNumber())); 
        messageParams.add(new BasicNameValuePair("From", BoundaryNumber)); 
        messageParams.add(new BasicNameValuePair("Body", message));
        messageFactory.create(messageParams);
    } catch (TwilioRestException e) {
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

I'm following the example very closely, however, it seems like I'm getting an SSLPeerUnverifiedException:

```
Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLPeerUnverifiedException: peer not authenticated
at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SSLSessionImpl.getPeerCertificates(SSLSessionImpl.java:352)
at org.apache.http.conn.ssl.AbstractVerifier.verify(AbstractVerifier.java:128)
at org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLSocketFactory.connectSocket(SSLSocketFactory.java:397)
at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnectionOperator.openConnection(DefaultClientConnectionOperator.java:148)
at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPoolEntry.open(AbstractPoolEntry.java:149)
at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPooledConnAdapter.open(AbstractPooledConnAdapter.java:121)
at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.tryConnect(DefaultRequestDirector.java:573)
at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:425)
at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:820)
at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:754)
at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:732)
at com.twilio.sdk.TwilioRestClient.request(TwilioRestClient.java:416)
... 11 more
```

I'm using a trial account and making an SMS from my Twilio number (BoundaryNumber) to my mobile (which is registered in Twilio) Now I've done a little digging and found some similar problems. For instance, [Bryan seems to be on the right track here.](http://forum.twilio.com/twilio/topics/java_twiliorestclient_peer_not_authenticated)

I'm just not sure how to fix the certificate issue. I'm not sure where to find the twilio certs, and a lot of the command line advice doesn't really work on OS X (10.9 Mavericks). I believe [certs are managed with the Keychain access tool on OS X.](http://www.charlesproxy.com/documentation/using-charles/ssl-certificates/)

Comment: Is it reproducible? Eg do you get it every time you make requests or only some of the time?

Comment: Yes, it happens every time.

Comment: I have a similar problem with mavericks. You could try to turn on java-ssl logging( -Djavax.net.debug=ssl). If I do so, I can see following error:
http-bio-8000-exec-1, handling exception: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unexpected error: java.security.InvalidAlgorithmParameterException: the trustAnchors parameter must be non-empty
http-bio-8000-exec-1, SEND TLSv1 ALERT:  fatal, description = internal_error
http-bio-8000-exec-1, WRITE: TLSv1 Alert, length = 2

Comment: I also get:

main, handling exception: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unexpected error: java.security.InvalidAlgorithmParameterException: the trustAnchors parameter must be non-empty
main, SEND TLSv1 ALERT:  fatal, description = internal_error
main, WRITE: TLSv1 Alert, length = 2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Somehow there is a problem with Mavericks. It crashes the JDK Installation during the update. My solution was for this problem to remove and reinstall the newest version of the jdk (http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk7-downloads-1880260.html).

Comment: Did you explicitly remove the jdk before reinstalling? (If so, how?) I just reinstalled, and I'm still getting the error.

Comment: I figured it out. I needed to set IntelliJ to use my new 1.7 install. Thank you! My app works at last :)